# Accessing an address held within an address

Tags: c, pointers

```
function(void * p)
```

`p` is an address containing an address to a struct. I cannot get from the given address to the address within to display the data that it points to. There is a really simple solution to do this, however I do not know how to dereference from the given address, and use the information I get as a new address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cast to the type you're looking for.

```
MyStruct **pps = (MyStruct**)p;
(**pps).Member = ...
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. For silly reasons I was ignoring the fact I could do it this way, and was looking for something that would do it all at once. This lead to the solution I really needed. Thank you for your help.